# How to generate with SQL activity ranges given dates of events?

Tags: sql, select

I have a table in the following format:

```
| user_name | date       | number_of_visits |
| cat005    | 2015-06-03 |      5           |
| cat005    | 2015-06-08 |      1           |
| dog009    | 2015-06-01 |      7           |
| dog009    | 2015-06-19 |      2           |
```

So, for each user I have number of visits for a given date. If there were not visit at a given date for a given user, then there is no records in the data bases (in other words we do not `save number_of_visits` if it is equal to zero).

Now I would like to use this table to generate another one in which for each user we have activity ranges. Here we used the following definition of being active: User is considered as "active" at a given day if he made at least one visit within the last 10 days. So, I would like to have something like that:

```
| user_name | active_start | active_end |
| cat005    | 2015-03-02   | 2015-03-25 |    
| cat005    | 2015-03-29   | 2015-06-01 |
| dog009    | 2015-04-01   | 2015-06-01 |
```

Please note that the data in the two examples are not consistent. According to the used definition `active_end` is exclusive (which means that the user did not have a visit at this date). For example the first line in the above table means that the user was active at `2015-03-02` (he/she made at least one visit). One can also say that at `2015-03-01` (one day before) this user was not active, which, in its turn means that he/she made no visits for more that 10 days. One can also say that at `2015-03-25` use made no visit and it was day 11th day without visit (so, the user was "switched" by the system to an inactive state).

How can one generated the second table using SQL.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using?  And your desired results don't correspond to the sample data.  You should fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.  One approach is to determine where active periods begin.  Then use a cumulative sum of previous actives for days.  This cumulative sum provides an aggregation criterion.

The following identifies the active days:

```
select t.*,
       (select t.*,
               (case when date > lag(date) over (partition by user_name order by date) + 10 -- date arithmetic varies by database
                     then 1
                     else 0
                end) as StartPeriodFlag
from table t;
```

Then the cumulative sum provides the information needed for grouping:

```
with t as (
      select t.*,
             (select t.*,
                     (case when date > lag(date) over (partition by user_name order by date) + 10 -- date arithmetic varies by database
                           then 1
                           else 0
                      end) as StartPeriodFlag
      from table t
     )
select user_name, min(date) as startdate,
       max(date) + 10 as enddate
from (select t.*,
             sum(StartPeriodFlag) over (partition by user_name order by date) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by user_name, grp;
```

As mentioned in a comment above, date arithmetic varies by database.  This uses the simple `+ 10` but the exact functions might differ by database.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70f07/15)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVITY ( user_name, "date", number_of_visits ) AS
          SELECT 'cat005', DATE'2015-06-03', 5 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'cat005', DATE'2015-06-08', 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dog009', DATE'2015-06-01', 7 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'dog009', DATE'2015-06-19', 2 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH changes AS (
  SELECT user_name,
         "date",
         CASE WHEN "date" <= LAG( "date" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY "date" ) + INTERVAL '10' DAY
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1 END AS change_group
  FROM   ACTIVITY
),
groups AS (
  SELECT user_name,
         "date",
         SUM( change_group ) OVER ( PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY "date" ) AS grp
  FROM   changes
)
SELECT  user_name,
        MIN( "date" ) AS activity_start,
        MAX( "date" ) + INTERVAL '10' DAY AS activity_end
FROM    groups
GROUP BY
        USER_NAME,
        GRP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70f07/15/0)**:

```
| USER_NAME |         ACTIVITY_START |           ACTIVITY_END |
|-----------|------------------------|------------------------|
|    dog009 | June, 19 2015 00:00:00 | June, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
|    dog009 | June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | June, 11 2015 00:00:00 |
|    cat005 | June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | June, 18 2015 00:00:00 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
WITH changes AS (
  SELECT user_name,
         "date",
         CASE WHEN "date" <= LAG( "date" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY "date" ) + INTERVAL '10' DAY
              THEN null
              ELSE "date" END AS first_date,
         CASE WHEN "date" >= LEAD( "date" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY "date" ) - INTERVAL '10' DAY
              THEN null
              ELSE "date" + INTERVAL '10' DAY END AS last_date
  FROM   ACTIVITY
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       user_name,
       LAST_VALUE(  first_date ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY "date" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS activity_start,
       FIRST_VALUE( last_date  ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY user_name ORDER BY "date" ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS activity_end
FROM   changes
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/70f07/15/1)**:

```
| USER_NAME |         ACTIVITY_START |           ACTIVITY_END |
|-----------|------------------------|------------------------|
|    cat005 | June, 03 2015 00:00:00 | June, 18 2015 00:00:00 |
|    dog009 | June, 01 2015 00:00:00 | June, 11 2015 00:00:00 |
|    dog009 | June, 19 2015 00:00:00 | June, 29 2015 00:00:00 |
```